# Having a subquery somehow do the same group by as the outer query

Tags: postgresql, group-by, subquery

i'm pretty decent with SQL but it's not my main experience of expertise. A colleague asked me a stumper of a question the other day. I was wondering if you guys could provide assistance.

Basically we're doing an over all count and grouping these counts by days... but we'd also like to kind of subquery those counts to get a specific type of count.

This is what I have so far that's not quite right.

```
select d.start_date, 
       count(a.status),
       (   select count(checked_ins) as checked_ins 
           from (   select distinct(a.id) as checked_ins 
                    from schema1.employee_se_assignment a, 
                         schema2.se d
                    where a.se_id= d.id  
                      and a.status not in ('unassigned')
                      and d.customer_name in (‘Test Client’)
                      and a.status = 'checked_in'
                ) src
       )
from schema1.employee_se_assignment a, 
     schema2.se d
where a.se_id= d.id
  and a.status not in ('unassigned') 
  and d.customer_name in (‘Test Client’)
  and a.status = 'checked_in'
group by d.start_date
Order by d.start_date
```

that yields the following results. which is almost what he wants. but it's clearly yielding the total of all of a certain type of status when we want it broken down by day. EG (see below):

[image: g]

Comment: Side note: Distinct is not a function, so `distinct(a.id)` is the same as `distinct a.id`. Distinct applies to the whole row, not a particular column. I often see `distinct(a), b` which is legal (since () is removed), but confusing since it means `distinct a, b`.

Comment: I suggest you create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=06073f8adae8d59fb89c8a415d4b398f with a small set of sample data that illustrates the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is legal, but confusing and a bad idea, that you use the same table aliases in different levels of the query.  You could likely do what you want by adding the condition `and d.start_date = d2.start_date` in the subquery, but of course you would have to have one of the aliases be "d2" rather than "d" to do that.

But it seems like you could get rid of the subquery altogether by doing:

```
select d.start_date, 
       count(a.status),
       count(distinct a.id) as checked_ins
from schema1.employee_se_assignment a, 
     schema2.se d
where a.se_id= d.id
  and a.status not in ('unassigned') 
  and d.customer_name in (‘Test Client’)
  and a.status = 'checked_in'
group by d.start_date
Order by d.start_date
```

Although these do differ in how NULL values of a.id are tallied, if it is possible for there to be any of these.

Comment: your query doesn't yield the results we want. i'm not looking to count status and distinct ids as total where all are status checked_in... i want count of all statuses and then count of all statuses that are value checked_in grouped by date.

Comment: It seems your example query has little to do with what you want, then.  Please fix your example so that it gets at least slightly close to what you want.  Then we can help you get the rest of the way there.